# Change color of navbar list item text in _Layout.cshtml when page is selected by user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, html-lists

1. I am using a bootstrap navbar in my _Layout.cshtml.
2. On my Index page, the list item "Home" shows as `color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781)` and the "Features" list item shows as `color: green`

**Desired Result:** When I click the "Features" link and navigate to the `Features.cshtml` page, I want the "Features" list item to change color to `color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781)` and the Home item to change to `color: green`.

This is easy to do if I put the navbar markup into every cshtml page. But I would like to just have my bootstrap navbar once in my `_Layout.cshtml` page.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781)" asp-page="Index")>@_loc["Home"]</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: green" asp-page="Features" localize-content>@_loc["Features"]</a>
                </li>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have this working fine by putting the HTML for the menu bar in every page, but that is not a good solution as I will have to separately maintain a number of instances of my menu bar.

I tried a number of stackoverflow items but didn't find one that worked for this case. Such as [set Different colors in asp:DropDownList Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926663/set-different-colors-in-aspdropdownlist-items)

I tried following the MSDocs for the `ForeColor` property but couldn't achieve this either.

I have also tried using `[ViewData]` set in my `Index.cshtml.cs` but still couldn't figure out how to change the color on page load or when navigating to the Features page.

I have also tried adding @ code directly to my _Layout page, such as `@if(this.Page = "Index")` and `@if(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory = "Index")` but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Desired Result**: When I click the "Features" link and navigate to the `Features.cshtml` page, I want the "Features" list item to change color to `color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781)` and the Home item to change to `color: green`.

If you'd like to dynamically set `color` for active item, you can store active page name in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then you can retrieve the stored data and dynamically set custom class for specific element to apply expected color to it in _Layout page, like below.

Html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active" onclick="changeactive('Home')">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-page="Index" )>@_loc["Home"]</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active" onclick="changeactive('Features')">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-page="Features" localize-content>@_loc["Features"]</a>
        </li>
        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS code

```
<script>
    function changeactive(pname) {

        //console.log(pname);

        localStorage.setItem("activepage", pname);
    }

    $(function () {
        var pname = localStorage.getItem("activepage");

        if (pname == "Home" || pname == "" || pname == null) {
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("active-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("normal-item");
        } else {
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active-item");
        }
    })
</script>
```

CSS class

```
<style>
    .active-item {
        color: green !important;
    }

    .normal-item {
        color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781) !important;
    }
</style>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! A few things clicked for me when implementing this and working around a few changes. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: This needs to use sessionStorage() instead of localStorage().

Answer (score 4):

> Change colour of the navbar element corresponding to the active page

I've had success using a custom tag helper for this, using some code inspirited from [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2078202.aspx?Tag+helper+to+highlight+the+active+page+in+navbar).

[image]

The Microsoft doc on creating tag helpers is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Third party tutorial available [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-tag-helpers-with-asp-net-core-mvc/).

The tag helper will let us specify the action that corresponds to each navbar item, then when the page is being built on the server we will [add the `active` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268536/add-css-class-to-html-element-in-a-taghelper) to the corresponding item.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li navigation-active-for="/Index" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li navigation-active-for="/Privacy" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </li>
    <li navigation-active-for="/Movies/Index" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/Movies/Index">Movies</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this case, the `navigation-active-for` attribute will be used.

The tag helper will be as follows
(in my case, the project is called Emotify)

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace Emotify.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("li", Attributes = _for)]
    public class ActiveItemTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private readonly IUrlHelper _urlHelper;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccess;
        private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
        private const string _for = "navigation-active-for";

        public ActiveItemTagHelper(
            IActionContextAccessor actionAccess,
            IUrlHelperFactory factory,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpAccess,
            LinkGenerator generator
        )
        {
            _urlHelper = factory.GetUrlHelper(actionAccess.ActionContext);
            _httpAccess = httpAccess;
            _linkGenerator = generator;
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            // grab attribute value
            var targetPage = output.Attributes[_for].Value.ToString();
            // remove from html so user doesn't see it
            output.Attributes.Remove(output.Attributes[_for]);
            
            // get the URI that corresponds to the attribute value
            var targetUri = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(_httpAccess.HttpContext, page: targetPage);
            // get the URI that corresponds to the current page's action
            var currentUri = _urlHelper.ActionLink();

            // if they match, then add the "active" CSS class
            if (targetUri == currentUri) {
                output.AddClass("active", HtmlEncoder.Default);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The services used in the constructor from dependency injection must be registered in `Startup.cs::ConfigureServices`.
[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037374/11141271) [ref](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3936#issuecomment-194367440)

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

**Important**: in [order to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271514/custom-tag-helper-not-working) the tag helper must be registered, like in `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

```
@using Emotify
@addTagHelper *, Emotify
```

Note that this **ISNT** `@addTagHelper *, Emotify.TagHelpers` since that's wrong apparently, doesn't work. I'm not sure how namespace nesting works in C#.

## Additional notes

- [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791439/11141271)
- I'm very new to C# and Razor, so this may not follow best practices